# Socket.io node.js, how to log connection times avoid or account for page refresh/multiple sockets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

By now, I'm completely confused by socket.io, what a socket actually is, etc. What I need to be able to do is connect two users identified via an 'id' (as a URL parameter) to a room, also defined as a URL parameter like so:

```
http://www.example.com/room1/user1
http://www.example.com/room1/user2
```

Client side:

```
var socket = io();
```

On the server:

```
app.get('/:id/:role', function(request, response) {
        var room = request.params.id;
        var user = request.params.role;
        io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
                      socket.join(room);
                      console.log(user+' has connected to '+room)
                      socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                                socket.leave(room);
                                console.log(user +' has disconnected from '+room);
                                });
                      });

        response.render('pages/room');
        });
```

What I need to be able to do here is log the connection times and disconnect times for those 2 users, in that specific 'room'. Connection and disconnection console statements work, but they end up getting logged multiple times, and upon a page refresh they start to get logged many, many times:

```
11:20:23 web.1  | user1 has connected to room1 at 1439220023347 //user1 connects
11:20:41 web.1  | user1 has disconnected from room1 at 1439220041842 //user 1 navigates away from page
11:20:44 web.1  | user1 has connected to room1 at 1439220044447 //user 1 returns back to page via back button
11:21:01 web.1  | user1 has connected to room1 at 1439220061168 //user 2 connects to room creates 2 new connection log events?
11:21:01 web.1  | user2 has connected to room1 at 1439220061168

11:23:04 web.1  | user1 has disconnected from room1 at 1439220184527 //user 1 hits 'refresh' all hell breaks loose
11:23:04 web.1  | user1 has connected to room1 at 1439220184727
11:23:04 web.1  | user2 has connected to room1 at 1439220184727
11:23:04 web.1  | user1 has connected to room1 at 1439220184727
```

How can I get to a point where a disconnect/connect event is fired only once for each user so I can log the event(s) reliably server side? (ultimately saving to a DB, but left out for ease of reading).

Comment: This is of course because you're creating multiple event listeners for the `connection` event, and then having all future connections join the room. This setup will not work, you'll need to change it up completely. I would start by not using express routing for this, and instead handle it using socket.io emits and events.

Comment: That does not look like pure node... you have express over it or something? Anyway, from the looks of it each time the page is accessed, you create a listener. So basically first time you access, you add a listener, so it logs once. Second time you add another one, so it logs two times. Etc. You need to put the listener code outside the app.get part.

Comment: @zozo Sorry, yes, using express. Ok, will look at how I can do it through emits and events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){`... is the main event handler for your socket, it needs to fire only once or else you'll be recreating a handler everytime your route is called. Typically it would look like this :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

As you can see, the route handling is totally independant from the socket event handling.

Now, you want to use URL parameters to join rooms. Because the socket connection is **made by the client**, it occurs **after** the route has been called in express, therefore, the client can send those parameters to the socket. 
(Untested) simplistic example.

Client :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000'); //adjust to the port your server is listening on
socket.on('auth',function(){
   socket.emit('userParameters',{room:room,user:user});
});
```

Server :

```
app.get('/:id/:role', function(request, response) {
   response.render('pages/room');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('auth'); //will be emitted only once to each socket.
    socket.on('userParameters',function(params){
         socket.join(params.room);
         socket.user = params.user;
         console.log(socket.user+' has connected to '+params.room)
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
          console.log(socket.user+' has disconnected'); //disconnecting automatically removes the socket from the room.
    });
});
```

I strongly recommend that you read the [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/), especially the Express examples.

Also, please consider that a lot of the documentation you'll read online is about Socket.IO<1.0, and there are a few differences in the syntax. [Read here to avoid confusion](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/)

Comment: I don't know, someone did... I haven't tried this yet. I appreciate the answer, I'll let you know how I get on with that.

Comment: Took a bit of fiddling on my part but this seems to do exactly what I need, thank you so much, saved me a ton of head scratching.