# Using socket.io with express 4 and jade template

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I'm trying to use `socket.io` with express but I couldn't make it work

Here my files:

roo:`/app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//Routes files
var maketurn = require('./routes/maketurn');

var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(3000));

// view engine setupe
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/maketurn', maketurn);
module.exports = app;
```

This is my controller (router)

roo:`/routes/maketurn.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8088, function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port and socket " + 3000);
});

var io = socketio.listen(server);

router
    .get('/', function (req, res) {
        io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            console.log('conectado el pendejo');
            socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});
            socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
            });
        });
        res.render('turns/maketurn', {title: 'Make Turn'});
    })

module.exports = router;
```

and this is my template (the client):

root: `views/turns/maketurn.jade`

```
extends ../layouts/turns

block content

    script.
        var socket = io.connect('httt://localhost:8088/maketurn');

        socket.on('news', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', {my: 'data'});
        });
        socket.on('connection', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', {my: 'data'});
        });

    .container
        form(method='post' action='#' role='form' id='turn')
            .wsn-form-control
                label Nombre y apellido
                input(name='name' type='text' id='name')
```

Comment: "Couldn't make it work" tells us nothing. What exactly happens/doesn't happen?

Comment: You've made two separate `app` variables and tried to start two web servers and two socket.io listeners each on a different port.  Is that really what you want.

Comment: Hi guys, I want to start a just listener and use it in various views or controller of view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your socket event handler outside of your router, check out this answer I wrote a couple of hours ago to a user with the same issue :

[Socket.io node.js, how to log connection times avoid or account for page refresh/multiple sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923483/socket-io-node-js-how-to-log-connection-times-avoid-or-account-for-page-refresh/31924051#31924051)

And the example from the Socket.io website which shows the same thing :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! 

but can't I use socket on routes?

Comment: You can store your sockets/users in an array and use them within the route handler, but the io.on('connection'... needs to be outside the router so it doesn't get called each time someone reaches the route

Comment: Thanks  xShirase

Can you give some example about use socket in routes?

Comment: That would require another question, after you've tried to figure it out yourself ;)